# How can I remove multiple Home entries in the menu of the Files launcher icon?

Tags: unity, nautilus, launcher

When I right-click the Files launcher icon, it displays multiple Home entries.

How can I remove all of them but one?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entries just don't show the correct name, instead of **Home** these entries should be shown :

1. entry = **Documents** (`/home/orschiro/Documents`)
2. entry = **Downloads** (`/home/orschiro/Downloads`)
3. entry = **Music** (`/home/orschiro/Music`)
4. entry = **Pictures** (`/home/orschiro/Pictures`)
5. entry = **Videos** (`/home/orschiro/Videos`)

Unlock Files from the launcher and check the content of the `nautilus.desktop` file - execute :

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop
```

This is the default content of the file, in case it is different, change the content back to default :

```
[Desktop Entry]
NotShowIn=Unity;
Name=Files
Comment=Access and organize files
Keywords=folder;manager;explore;disk;filesystem;
Exec=nautilus --new-window %U
Icon=system-file-manager
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;Core;FileManager;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=nautilus
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.20.3
X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true
Actions=new-window;
X-Unity-IconBackgroundColor=#af4853
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nautilus

X-AppStream-Ignore=true

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=New Window
Exec=nautilus --new-window
```

Logout and back in, lock Files back to the launcher and now it should show the correct entries :

[image]

In case that you created an individual `.desktop` file, check the content of this file additionally :

```
nano /home/orschiro/.local/share/applications/<your-individual-files.desktop-file>
```

Also make sure that these entries in `/home/orschiro/.config/user-dirs.dirs` are matching :

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I have found the problem. Can you confirm if it is not possible to use custom directories in `.config/user-dirs.dirs`? Please take a look at [this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/e2eqk0d.png).

Comment: @orschiro You can customize them, but it has to follow the default structure. In the screenshot are three Home entries where the name is missing ("$HOME/), I have added how it has to look like to the answer. :)